# RoleProvider injection with Ninject

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc, asp.net-roles

First off I want to say there is a ton of answers on SO and google searches surrounding this, however I'm running into an issue that prevents those solutions from working. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241542/asp-net-mvc-3-ninject-custom-membership-and-role-provider) seems to be the way to go. (`kernel.Inject(Roles.Provider);`)

The issue that I'm having is that when I'm trying to inject the `RoleProvider` `Roles.Provider` is null, however my custom provider is found in the list within `Roles.Providers`. I am thinking that Ninject is trying to access the role provider too soon.

In my `NinjectWebCommon` class it appears that it's using `WebActivator` to start itself. `[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Admin.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]`

It appears that all of the articles I've come across are using older versions of Ninject and are doing a lot of the heavy lifting in the Global.asax Application_Start... Using my implementation how can I get DI working for a custom role provider?

I'm using the `[Inject]` attribute within my custom provider.

Answer (score 1):

The `WebActivator` pipeline runs way before even the standard ASP.NET stack is created. It means that you won't have access to anything created by ASP.NET during bootstrap in `NinjectWebCommon`.

Use that file only to declare bindings that **do not depend** on ASP.NET stuff to be up.
In order to get around this issue, you should use `Global.asax` `Application_Start` handler to load any additional modules/bindings that are dependend on ASP.NET stuff such as `Roles.Provider`.

Here is a suggestion that may solve your problem:

```cs
public void Application_Start()
{
    var kernel = (new Bootstrapper()).Kernel;
    kernel.Inject(Roles.Provider);

    //Other initialization stuff
}
```

The `Bootstrapper` class is a lazy singleton that has a static `IKernel` initialized within your `NinjectWebCommon.cs`. So this is the proper way of retrieving the configured kernel instance from *outside* your `NinjectWebCommon`.

Give it a try.